# "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'totalAmount'"

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am learning MongoDB and trying implementing aggregations related command.

The collection looks like this :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bbc185f132cf4170a2f5fd3"), "custID" : "A123", "Amount" : 500, "status" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bbc187d132cf4170a2f5fd4"), "custID" : "A123", "Amount" : 250, "status" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bbc188d132cf4170a2f5fd5"), "custID" : "B212", "Amount" : 200, "status" : "A" }
```

The first query is `Find out total amount for individual customer ID having status ‘A’`

From this I coded this :

`db.emp.aggregate([{$match:{'status':'A'}},{'totalAmount':{$sum:'$Amount'}}])`

But getting this error :

`"errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'totalAmount'"`

Where am I going wrong ?

Also, I know that I am going to get a lot of error and doubts later. Is there any good platform where I can ask such questions rather than putting them on SO.

Comment: MongoDb has a fixed list of [Aggregation Pipeline Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) - `totalAmount` is not one of these (i.e. it's an *Unrecognized pipeline stage name*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

`totalAmount` is not an aggregation pipeline stage. There are some operator given in the mongodb pipeline stages only that can be used in the [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/). And also you need to use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)
 stage to get summation of all the similar `custId` with the [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator.

```
db.emp.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "status": "A" }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$custID",
    "Amount": { "$sum": "$Amount" }
  }}
])
```